# Saveing data on iCloud

Tags: ios, object, icloud

I want save some data on `iCloud` just like structure - image,first name,last name,string id,string id2,xyz string fields are saved on `iCloud` and how to retrieve and how to multiple action occurred just like delete,update...

Comment: if u only need to save some data online , you can use Parse.com

Comment: ya but i want save data on iCloud not parse.com